# how to get value on array javascript based index

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to get value on array javascript based index?

example :

```
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

how to implements logic like below :

```
 [offset...length]

 [2..3] ==> result [3,4,5]
 [3..7] ==> result [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

how do that on javascript?

Comment: `my_array.slice(start, end + 1)` is what you need? [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: great thank you @fuyushimoya

Comment: hi @fuyushimoya, how to get range on slice?

array.slice(1,2) just return value based indexing? how to get value based offset & length?

Comment: For offset, use `my_array.slice(start, start + offset + 1)`;

Comment: still not have answer

Comment: I won't put it as an answer, and I have added some example to @Tilak Madichetti's. Feel free to accept it. Or if my 2nd expression just misused start as offset and offset as length, it's `my_array.slice(offset, offset + length+ 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Mr.fuyushimoya is right - You can use the :
JavaScript Array slice() Method

---

Definition and Usage:-
The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

Note: The original array will not be changed.

For more information , please refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) link.

Example:

```js
var origin = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var start = 3, end = 7, offset = 7;

// If you want values from index 3 to index 7
console.log(origin.slice(start, end + 1));

// If you want values from index 3 and the following 6 values.
console.log(origin.slice(start, start + offset + 1));
```

Comment: Just added some example on your answer.

Comment: Yeah   - that's awesome !!